# Prove that no such $f$ exists

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have come upon this question and could not find a solution for it.

Prove that there is no entire function $f$ such that $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ $\quad|f(z)|>|z|$.

Any ideas on how to solve this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac z {f(z)}$ for $z \neq 0$. (Note that $f(z) \neq 0$ for  $z \neq 0$). Then $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Since it is bounded it extends to an entire function $G$. This entire function is bounded. By Liouville's Theorem it must be a constant. This means $f(z)=cz$ for some constant, but then the given inequality does not hold at $0$.

Comment: why are you excluding $0$?

Comment: As a >5 year and >100 K user you *might* sense that such a question has been asked and answered before :)

Comment: @MartinR look at his reputation graph. saying he's a >5 year user is very misleading and irrelevant to your purposes

Comment: @mathworker21: Kavi is in the [top 30](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-analysis/topusers) list for complex analysis, and very active in the last years. He should know how to search for duplicates (it took me less than 2 minutes to find an identical question with answers). It is a pity that so many high-rep uses don't care about duplicates.

Comment: @MartinR okay? i stand by my last comment.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly there is no $z$ for which $f(z) = 0$. Therefore, $g(z) := \frac{z}{f(z)}$ is entire. Since $|z| < |f(z)|$, $|g(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. [Liouville](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Joseph_liouville.jpeg) implies $g(z) \equiv c$ is constant, i.e. $z \equiv cf(z)$. Clearly $c \not = 0$, so $f(0) = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Why $g(z)=0$ is not trivial from $g(z)=z/f(z)$ and Liouville theorem?

Comment: $g(z) = 0$ doesn't even follow at all...

Comment: I m still scratching my head to discard $g(z)=0$. Tell the reason.

Comment: if $c=0$, then $z \equiv 0$. that makes no sense. e.g. $z=1$, has $1 \not = 0$.

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$, hence the function $h(z):= \frac{z}{f(z)}$ is entire and we have $|h(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$.

Liouville tells us, that $h$ is constant. Thus, for some complex $c$ we have

$$\frac{z}{f(z)}=c$$

for all $z$. With $z=0$ we get $ c=0$, a contradiction.